# Is the waveshare 2.7 e-paper HAT ink display the right display for a pico?

Tags: pi-pico, micropython, circuitpython

I'm very new to programming on raspberry pi's and I haven't coded anything in about 5 years so bear with me.

My company is asking me to connect a 2.7 e-paper hat INK display to a raspberry pi pico. I've been following this  [adafruit circuitpython tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-libraries-on-any-computer-with-raspberry-pi-pico)  but i'm unsure if im on the right track. I've been looking at the [waveshare wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.7inch_e-Paper_HAT) and I'm havin issues following instructions on there, I'm unable to download those libraries required (BCM2835 and wiring pi.) i've been trying thonny, and the REPL.

Then I stumbled upon this page for the [2.7inch e-paper e-ink display for the pico](https://www.waveshare.com/pico-epaper-2.7.htm) and it has pretty straight forward directions to start programming with the pico. Are we using the wrong e-ink display? Or is it still possible to use a regular 2.7 e-paper instead of the pico version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the pico version. The regular version will NOT work. The regular version is designed for the regular raspberry pi, whereas the pico version is designed for the Pico.

However, if you are willing to study the docs and learn the code necessary to interact with the display, you could use the regular version.

Comment: Why won't the regular version work? What capabilities is the pico lacking?

Comment: From reading the Waveshare wiki, the only difference between the regular version and the pico version is just that the pin headers are designed to fit a pico. If you're designing you own board, then it doesn't matter which you use. The pico version may make for easier prototyping.

Comment: I edited my answer to accommodate the more advance programmers out there (The OP says they haven’t written a line of code in 5 years).

Comment: The programming will be identical between the two versions. The only difference between the two are the pinouts.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the sample Pico code at the Waveshare website.
https://www.google.com/search?q=Waveshare+e-paper+display+code+examples+for+Raspberry+Pico

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please take the tour and visit the help center to familiarize yourself with Stackexchange's way. Note that posting LMGTFY links is considered unfriendly language, please refer to the [be nice policy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/conduct). Also note that you should try to make an answer stand on it's own with a link only providing reference. As written now this is a link-only answer which might be deleted.